# Conformal mapping of the domain bounded by a line segment and a circular arc

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, conformal-geometry

I am trying to construct a conformal map from the region $R$ which is the set of points in the complex plane bounded by the segment connecting $i$ and $1$ and the part of the unit circle in the first quadrant to the unit disk $\mathbb{D}$.  I'm good with standard conformal map examples.  So I just need a way to map $R$ to a familiar space.  Thanks for any help.

Comment: Pick a Mobius transformation that sends $1$ to $0$ and $i$ to $\infty$. This will map your region to a region bounded by rays from $0$ to $\infty$. Rotate it so that one is the positive real axis, and then use an appropriate $z^\beta$ to map this region to the upper half plane.

Comment: So I picked $f(z) = \frac{z - 1}{z - i}$.  I think it maps the quarter circle onto the positive half of the imaginary line, and the line segment onto the positive real axis.  However, how do I know it maps onto the first quadrant?  Thanks.

Comment: I disagree that it maps the line segment to the positive real axis; your map seems to map it to the negative real axis. In addition, it seems to map the circular arc to $(-1+i)t$, $t \geq 0$.

Comment: I was hoping to leave the details as to why it surjects the region these two enclose rays enclose to you :)

Answer (score 2):

So, starting with $f(z) = \frac{z-1}{z-i}$, where does the region go?

Near $1$ we have $f(z) \sim \frac{z-1}{1-i}$. Since the argument of $1-i$ is $-\pi/4$, ths map $f$ rotates the neighborhood of $1$ by $\pi/4$ counterclockwise.  So, the circular arc (originally going straight up from $1$) is mapped to the line $\{(-1+i)t : t\ge 0\}$, as Mike Miller said. And the line segment, after rotation, goes to negative real axis. The image of the domain is between them.

Why is the map a surjection onto the region between these half-lines? Because it is a homeomorphism of the Riemann sphere onto itself, which implies that $\partial f(A) = f(\partial A)$ for every set $A$. So, the image of the domain is bounded by the image of the boundary.

Once you have the above, apply rotation (multiply by $e^{-3\pi/4}$), then power function, etc.